# Scala Map с динамическими ключами

Tags: map, scala

Коллеги, можно ли динамически создать мапку с ключами, в зависимости от своего условия(наличия значений)?

Например для объекта `Person`:

```
case class Person(name: String, surname: String, age: Int)
```

Сделать мапку с ключами, но не всеми, а по некому условию. Что-то вроде:

```
val p1 = Person("Вася", "", "35")
Map(
  if (p1.name.nonEmpty()) "name" -> p1.name,
  if (p1.surname.nonEmpty()) "surname" -> p1.surname,
  "age" -> p1.age.toString 
)
```

Таким образом для объекта `p1` должна получиться мапка не с тремя, а с двумя ключами:

```
Map("name" -> "Вася", "age" -> "35")
```

Ключ surname пропущен

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот так?

```
case class Person(name: String, surname: String, age: Int)

val p1 = Person("Вася", "", 35)

def person2MapVer1(p: Person): Map[String, String] = {
  var map = Map.empty[String, String]

  if (p.name.nonEmpty) map += "name" -> p.name

  if (p.surname.nonEmpty) map += "surname" -> p.surname

  map += "age" -> p.age.toString

  map
}


def person2MapVer2(p: Person): Map[String, String] = {
  val validateName: Person => Option[(String, String)] =
    p => if (p.name.nonEmpty) Some("name" -> p.name) else None

  val validateSurname: Person => Option[(String, String)] =
    p => if (p.surname.nonEmpty) Some("surname" -> p.surname) else None

  val validateAge: Person => Option[(String, String)] =
    p => Some("age" -> p.age.toString)

  val validations: List[Person => Option[(String, String)]] =
    List(validateName, validateSurname, validateAge)

  validations.foldLeft(Map.empty[String, String]) {
    case (acc, validation) => acc ++ validation(p)
  }
}

person2MapVer1(p1)
person2MapVer2(p1)
```

Comment: Ну да. Это очевидное решение. У меня полей в объекте довольно много, добавление каждого вызывает новую аллокацию мапки, если я все правильно понимаю. Мутабельную мапку тоже не хочется использовать. По идее что там должно быть а чего не должно известно до создания мапки, думал может через ее `apply` как-то можно.

Comment: Но тем не менее - это вполне себе решение проблемы, может и поможет кому-то. Отмечу ответом